# How to find and replace System.out.println with log.info using reg expression in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an old java project which contains more than 100 source files for which I need to add log4j, need to append all the data inside System.Out.println to log.info. Find and replace with reg expression might help me out with this. I am using eclipse 6.

Comment: I guess try locating _Find in projects..._ in menu or something like that. Also you could open all your *.java files with Notepad++ and it provides much greated _Find all in all opened documents_ feature.

Comment: find replace with regular expression should do the job and almost all IDE has that feature, all you need to have his write the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the eclipse feature Search feature it is very good for searching within the files as well. It is on eclipse toolbar Search>Java Search

In the search string type in the method name and then select "method" radio box. and hit search.

It is self explanatory you can search method, constructors extra

It is also very good if you want to search a string within the filename as well.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse I would use Ctrl+H to bring up the search menu. Go across the tabs at the top until you get to "File Search" type in your search string, "System.out.println(", tell it to search in your project for *.java files and then hit the replace button.

Answer (score 0):

---

sed -i "s/System.out.println/log.info/g" `grep System.out.println -rl /path`